# Slow query on Golang benchmark, but fast from psql

Tags: postgresql, go, benchmarking, go-gorm

I have the following benchmark in Go 1.19 and [Gorm](https://gorm.io/) with Postgresql 14.5:

```golang
func BenchmarkAvailableShippingMethods(b *testing.B) {
        err := DB.Exec("DELETE FROM shipping_method_costs").Error
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }
        err = DB.Exec("DELETE FROM shipping_methods").Error
        if err != nil {
            b.Fatal(err)
        }

        user := factories.ItalianUser(DB)
        factories.CreateManyShippingMethods(DB, 100_000, user.ID) // create 100000 records in bulk

        // time.Sleep(time.Minute)

        b.Run("benchmark", func(b *testing.B) {
            b.ResetTimer()
            for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
                b.StartTimer()
                availableShippingMethods, err := usr.AvailableShippingMethods(DB, user)
                b.StopTimer()
                if err != nil {
                    b.Fatal(err)
                }
                b.Logf("Available shipping methods found are %d", len(availableShippingMethods))
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Now when I run the benchmark I can see the following logs:

```
...
2022/09/21 06:32:31 /Users/pioz/Code/go/src/github.com/pioz/ct/usr/shipping_method.go:141
[0.265ms] [rows:12] SELECT * FROM "shipping_method_costs" WHERE "shipping_method_costs"."shipping_method_id" IN (3204275,3231642,3270298,3276705)

2022/09/21 06:32:31 /Users/pioz/Code/go/src/github.com/pioz/ct/usr/shipping_method.go:141
[71.786ms] [rows:4] SELECT "shipping_methods"."id","shipping_methods"."user_id","shipping_methods"."enabled","shipping_methods"."name","shipping_methods"."from_countries","shipping_methods"."to_countries","shipping_methods"."min_estimate_shipping_days","shipping_methods"."max_estimate_shipping_days","shipping_methods"."parcel","shipping_methods"."tracked","shipping_methods"."tracking_link","shipping_methods"."free_shipping_threshold_cents","shipping_methods"."free_shipping_threshold_quantity","shipping_methods"."max_cart_subtotal_cents","shipping_methods"."currency","shipping_methods"."created_at","shipping_methods"."updated_at" FROM "shipping_methods" INNER JOIN user_shipping_methods ON user_shipping_methods.shipping_method_id = shipping_methods.id INNER JOIN users ON user_shipping_methods.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 200054 AND enabled = 't' AND from_countries @> '"IT"' AND to_countries @> '"ES"'

2022/09/21 06:32:31 /Users/pioz/Code/go/src/github.com/pioz/ct/usr/shipping_method.go:141
[0.410ms] [rows:12] SELECT * FROM "shipping_method_costs" WHERE "shipping_method_costs"."shipping_method_id" IN (3204275,3231642,3270298,3276705)

2022/09/21 06:32:31 /Users/pioz/Code/go/src/github.com/pioz/ct/usr/shipping_method.go:141
[70.845ms] [rows:4] SELECT "shipping_methods"."id","shipping_methods"."user_id","shipping_methods"."enabled","shipping_methods"."name","shipping_methods"."from_countries","shipping_methods"."to_countries","shipping_methods"."min_estimate_shipping_days","shipping_methods"."max_estimate_shipping_days","shipping_methods"."parcel","shipping_methods"."tracked","shipping_methods"."tracking_link","shipping_methods"."free_shipping_threshold_cents","shipping_methods"."free_shipping_threshold_quantity","shipping_methods"."max_cart_subtotal_cents","shipping_methods"."currency","shipping_methods"."created_at","shipping_methods"."updated_at" FROM "shipping_methods" INNER JOIN user_shipping_methods ON user_shipping_methods.shipping_method_id = shipping_methods.id INNER JOIN users ON user_shipping_methods.user_id = users.id WHERE users.id = 200054 AND enabled = 't' AND from_countries @> '"IT"' AND to_countries @> '"ES"'
      15      73876214 ns/op
--- BENCH: BenchmarkAvailableShippingMethods/benchmark-10
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    shipping_method_test.go:419: Available shipping methods found are 4
    ... [output truncated]
PASS
```

The big query to retrieve the `shipping_methods` records on this benchmark takes an average time of ~70ms. BUT if I run the same query (with `EXPLAIN(ANALYSE)`) on `psql` I can see this:

```
 Nested Loop  (cost=20.92..77.41 rows=4 width=193) (actual time=0.237..0.278 rows=4 loops=1)
   ->  Index Only Scan using users_pkey on users  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=1 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (id = 200054)
         Heap Fetches: 1
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=20.50..68.93 rows=4 width=201) (actual time=0.222..0.262 rows=4 loops=1)
         ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on shipping_methods  (cost=20.08..51.18 rows=4 width=193) (actual time=0.136..0.160 rows=4 loops=1)
               Recheck Cond: ((from_countries @> '"IT"'::jsonb) AND (to_countries @> '"ES"'::jsonb))
               Filter: enabled
               Rows Removed by Filter: 7
               Heap Blocks: exact=11
               ->  Bitmap Index Scan on shipping_methods_enabled_from_countries_to_countries_idx1  (cost=0.00..20.08 rows=8 width=0) (actual time=0.128..0.128 rows=11 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((from_countries @> '"IT"'::jsonb) AND (to_countries @> '"ES"'::jsonb))
         ->  Index Only Scan using user_shipping_methods_user_id_shipping_method_id_idx on user_shipping_methods  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=16) (actual time=0.024..0.024 rows=1 loops=4)
               Index Cond: ((user_id = 200054) AND (shipping_method_id = shipping_methods.id))
               Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.444 ms
 Execution Time: 0.323 ms
```

The execution time is less than 1ms. How is possible? What am I missing? Is cache related issue?

I've also noticed that if I add a `time.Sleep` of 1 minute before the `b.Run` call the query time goes from 70ms to 1ms (are indices calculated in background??).

Comment: Could be a slow network, firewal, slow fetching recordsl or whatever. But the database is fast, not much to improver over there

Comment: The database is on localhost.

Comment: Run `ANALYZE table_name;` on all tables used in the query (or just `ANALYZE;` for all). Yes, there is a background task, which gather statistics about content of tables, which are used in queries https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html

Comment: I'm not a gorm user, but it looks like you prelude the benchmark by deleting and rebuilding two of the tables.  That probably means they need to be vacuumed and analyzed, but that hasn't been done yet at the time the benchmark starts running, but probably has been done when you go in later with psql.

Comment: Use [auto_explain](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) to capture the plans as they are actually run.

Comment: I've added `db.Exec("ANALYSE user_shipping_methods, shipping_method_costs, shipping_methods")` before starting the benchmark and now the query time goes from 70ms to 1ms.